# [meteor]How to put the merged css file at the bottom of the head?

Tags: css, vue.js, meteor

I'm using meteor + vue , but meteor automatically extracts the css, from the vue component within the npm and places it in the head, and causes the css conflict. How can this conflict be avoided?

Meteor 1.8.1
vue 2.6.5

[image]

There's a lot of css, on the page head that was originally inside vue component. I don't want that.

A lot of them, causing a lot of css conflicts on the page.

Please help me. Thank's a lot!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg1As.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXZFH.png)

the `<meteor-bundled-css />`  flag not work

because this tag does not put the merged file at the bottom of the head.  I'm so sad..

Comment: Vue is supposed to scope the styles to prevent conflict. How do you see the conflicts?

Comment: @ghybs thanks for answer:) .    Well, the reply doesn't seem to be able to send pictures. I'll try to reedit the question.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what actually bothers you... are you trying to just replace all the style tags by a bundle, or do you really see a conflict?

Comment: Yes,I import all the scss file in "/client/main.scss",and they go to the top of head. But some <style> tags in vue component also there which has not “scope” attribute. Because of the "dynamicHead" always be the bottom of  </head>.   Some css rule in my custom scss override by the css rule of the npm.  eg: .xx.yy  override by   .xx.yy (/node_modules/vue-materail/...).   Now I have a stupid way to solve it.   [Meteor forums with the question](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-prevent-meteor-pick-up-css-of-vue-components-in-the-npm/48580)      I want to know where I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[style in head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHx9v.png)

[scss file not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVJDH.png)

The correct way  ：

You can create  `.vueignore`  files with a RegEx on each line to exclude  `.vue`  files from the compilation based on their path. If the  `.vueignore`  is inside a folder, it only applies to that folder.

For example, you can add the following  `.vueignore`  file to your app inorder to ignore  `.vue`  files in the  `node_modules` folders:

```
node_modules/
```

Thanks for @ [Akryum](https://github.com/Akryum)  :clap: